# Is it possible to protect/ unprotect a cell based on value in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to accomplish the following with conditional formatting (or some other tool in Excel),

If the value in A1 is greater than 0, protect C1.
If the value in A1 in smaller or equal to 0, unprotect c1.

I'm not sure if this is even possible because it only has number, fond, border and fill options when I tried to format the cell.

Comment: You would need to use VBA for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a VBA solution to this problem.

In order for this solution to work you need to format all cells on the given worksheet as being "unlocked" when the worksheet is "protected", except for cell C1 which needs to remain locked.

Insert the following code in the code module of the worksheet you want to have the cell locked on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Me.Range("A1").AddressLocal = Target.AddressLocal And _
            Not (Me.Range("A1").Value2 = 0) Then
        Me.Protect
    ElseIf Me.Range("A1").AddressLocal = Target.AddressLocal Then
        Me.Unprotect
    End If
End Sub
```